# Kendo DropDownList OptionLabel never appears until it is opened and closed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

With the following, the `DropDownList` does not show anything upon load. When the page loads it should display **Select a code** and not blank. Works fine after I open/close it. Then the optional label is used. I added the `Text` / `SelectedIndex` properties while messing with this.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
   .Name("quickCodes")
   .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.QuickCodes)
   .Template("#if (data.OpCode) { # ${ data.Code } ${ data.OpCode } ${ data.Description } # } else { data.Code } #" +
             "<input type='hidden' name='DetailLines[#= index(data)#].QuickCodeId' value='#= data.Id #' />")
   .DataValueField("Code")
   .DataTextField("Code")
   .ValuePrimitive(true)
   .AutoBind(false)
   .OptionLabel("Select a code")
   .Text("Select a code")
   .SelectedIndex(0)
   .Events(o => o.Change("quickCodeAdd"))
```

)

Comment: you have set selected index to 0 and "Select a code" might not be in index 0 check the drop down and find the index of "select a code" and test it by changing the selectedIndex(x). Once it is confirmed this is the problem you cand then adjust the positino of select a code label

Comment: Kendo controls don't actually use a true 'select'. It's a bunch of spans internally and a div containing a ul element. So it's not possible to do this. However when the user clicks the dropdown and picks an item I am programatically calling select(0) and this does in fact select the option label (select a code). It's my understanding that the purpose of the option label is to fill this in without hassle.

Comment: Workaround: $("span.k-input").text("Select a code").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like with AutoBind set to false there is an issue with OptionLabel/Text. Below code worked which is more equal to the work around you have suggested.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("color")
      .DataTextField("Code")
      .DataValueField("Code")
      .AutoBind(false)
      .Text("Select Code")
      .OptionLabel("Select code")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { value = "Select code" })
      .BindTo(ViewBag.QuickCodes)

)
```